# Unable to use mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc when building from azure cloudshell (powershell)

Tags: azure, powershell, docker, cloud

This works perfectly when I build locally, but to avoid having to move images to the azure container registry I am trying to build in the cloud.

Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc AS build-stage1

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
    .
    .
    .

Step 5/37 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc AS build-stage1
manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
2019/10/01 14:32:28 Container failed during run: build. No retries remaining.
failed to run step ID: build: exit status 1

Run ID: ch1k failed after 7s. Error: failed during run, err: exit status 1
```

---

And yet the same base image works fine when I build from a locally hosted powershell.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: What is the reason that you leave without any response while someone is helping you?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to try this until today.  Still seeing the same issue, for now I am building locally and pushing to azure which does seem to work although it is slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear how do you build the image successfully. But I recommend you take a look at the image [`mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore) in the docker hub. And it also gives out the available tags [here](https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/servercore/tags/list). There is no tag as `ltsc`. You need to choose one in the available tags. For example, `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`.

**Update:**

I can reproduce the same issue as you got, then I add the parameter `--platform windows` and it works perfectly. I recommend you take a try. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I wasn't able to try it until today as I got pulled off to look at another urgent problem.  I still see manifest unknown with ltsc2019, and it works fine building locally. `Step 5/37 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 AS build-stage1
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries`

Comment: @GaryCameron I update the answer with the test. You can take a try. And if it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you, yes adding this to the docker build invocation allowed me to get past this.  `Step 5/37 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 AS build-stage1
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
65014b3c3121: Already exists
12c8dbabfd62: Pulling fs layer
12c8dbabfd62: Verifying Checksum
12c8dbabfd62: Download complete
12c8dbabfd62: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:404e0ee336a063619d1e93a2446061cf19cb3068bacb1775f5613e3b54e527e1
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
 ---> 739b21bd02e7`

Comment: @GaryCameron That's the news what I want to hear :-)